# Question about Visual C++ Properties

Tags: c++

Could someone explain this line:

> In more complicated contexts, such as "+=", a **rewrite** is performed by
>   doing both get and put.

Taken from: [MSDN - Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfk0thd.aspx)

What do they mean by rewrite?Is it a compile-time rewrite or does it induce run-time overhead?As far as I know in release mode properties are compiled to the same thing, so they must have the same performance as getters/setters, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  If `+=` means what I think it means, it performs a `get` to get the original value, adds 1 to it, and then performs a `put` to write the new value, which is what I assume they mean by rewriting the value.

Comment: @RobertHarvey so with optimizations it compiles to the same ASM code as having the value as public, right?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  Read the description at the top of the page, which states: *"The compiler treats these 'virtual data members' as data members by changing their references into function calls."*

Comment: I think it's referring to the possiblity of using it with virtual methods as get and set parameters in the property.

Comment: It still means an additional level of indirection.  Accessing a property via its getter or setter is not at all the same thing as accessing a public member variable directly.

Answer (score 1):

As you see in complete paragraph in MSDN page to that you referred, all work is done by compiler.

> When **the compiler** sees a data member declared with this attribute on the right of a member-selection operator ("." or "->"), it converts the operation to a get or put function, depending on whether such an expression is an l-value or an r-value. In more complicated contexts, such as "+=", a rewrite is performed by doing both get and put.

By then it means that following line:

```
s.the_prop = 5;
n = s.the_prop;
```

compiled to:

```
s.putprop(5);
n = getprop();
```

A complicated case like:

```
s.the_prop += 5;
```

compiled to:

```
s.putprop(s.getprop() + 5);
```

I think *it is not as complicated as* they said in MSDN!